# Use of tilde symbol $\sim$ irrespective of its general use

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, notation, circles, absolute-value

I know that the tilde is used for asymptotic equivalence and symmetry in geometric figures. But here in my highschool textbook it is been used as follows: [image]
$d = r_1 \sim r_2$

i.e. $d = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
r_1 - r_2, r_1 \ge r_2\\
r_2 - r_1, r_2 \ge r_1\\
\end{aligned}
\right.$

*Now the question is that:*
**Is it acceptable of writers to use such a non-general way of saying this?** How can they use such notation in such a vague manner?

**According to me it is mathematically equivalent to just saying $d = |r_1 - r_2|$? Am I correct?**

Comment: You can define any operator to be defined as anything including ~@#\$%&^_?, so I can define $a @ b:=\frac{1,(\frac{1,a}+\frac{1,b})}$ if I wanted to. Here they define the ~ operator to be the metric induced from the $L^1$ norm over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, it should have been $|r_1-r_2|$.

Comment: I agree it is pretty confusing. But then authors of elementary level textbooks often think that by introducing their own clumsy notation instead of the standard one they will make life easier ("less scary") for the students.

Comment: I don't see the tilde in the posted text.

Comment: @Rainb Yaa Anyways I must say that I am a complete stranger to these terminologies such as "metric induced , norm etc " However I know we can define it just like we would do with functions. nd that is the catch

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Hmmmm their thoughts will remain like this etched in their textbook...life wont be easier but be the other way round for readers. Lol "Less scary" was a nice one tho. It got me.

Comment: @DanielP Yaa! Anyways what should I do next? delete the question?